# DB Architecture: One table using WHERE vs multiple

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, low-latency

I wonder what is the difference between having one table with 6 millions row (aka with a huge DB) and 100k active users:

```
CREATE TABLE shoes (
id serial primary key,
color text,
is_left_one boolean,
stock int
);
```

With also 6 index like:

```
CREATE INDEX blue_left_shoes ON shoes(color,is_left_one) WHERE color=blue AND is_left_one=true;
```

Versus: 6 tables with 1 million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE blue_left_shoes(
id serial primary key,
stock int
);
```

The latter one seems more efficient because users don't have to ask for the condition since the table IS the condition, but perhaps creating the indexes mitigate this?

This table is used to query either left, right, "blue", "green" or "red" shoes and to check the number of remaining items, but it is a simplified example but you can think of Amazon (or any digital selling platform) tooltip "only 3 items left in stock" for the workload and the usecase. It is the users (100k active daily) who will make the query.

NB: The question is mostly for PostgreSQL but differences with other DB is still relevant and interesting.

Comment: `is_left_one acts as a boolean value.` Then, by all means, make it `boolean`. Also, your question is going nowhere without defining the workload and role of the table(s). If you never query the whole table, only one of the 6 partitions, then the unified table has mostly disadvantages.

Comment: Ok I edited for bool and will add the requested details

Comment: 6 million rows is not considered "huge" these days. I wouldn't even consider it "large".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latter case, where you use a table called `blue_left_shoes`

- Your code needs to first work out which table to look at (as opposed to parameterising a value in the where clause)
- As permutations and options increase, you need to increase the number of tables, and increase the logic in your app that works out which table to use
- Anything that needs to use this database (i.e. a reporting tool or an API) now needs to re implement all of these rules

You are imposing logic at a high layer to improve performance.

If you were to partition and/or index your table appropriately, you get the same effect - SQL queries only look through the records that matter. The difference is that you don't need to implement this logic in higher layers

As long as you can get the indexing right, keeping this is one table is almost always the right thing to do.

## Partitioning

Database partitioning is where you select one or more columns to decide how to "split up" your table. In your case you could choose (color, is_left_one).

Now your table is logically split and ordered in this way and when you search for blue,true it automatically knows which partition to look in. It doesn't look in any other partitions (this is called partition pruning)

Note that this occurs automatically from the search criteria. You don't need to manually work out a particular table to look at.

- Partitioning doesn't require any extra storage (beyond various metadata that has to be saved)
- You can't apply multiple partitions to a table. Only one

## Indexing

Creating an index also provides performance improvements. However indexes take up space and can impact insert and update performance (as they need to be maintained). Practically speaking, the select trade off almost always far outweighs any insert/update negatives

You should always look at indexes before partitioning

## Non selective indexes

In your particular case, there's an extra thing to consider: a boolean field is not "selective". I won't go into details but suffice to say you shouldn't create an index on this field alone, as it won't be used because it only halves the number of records you have to look through. You'd need to include some other fields in any index (i.e. colour) to make it useful

Comment: Excluding time taken in the application layer? If you got your indexes right on the full table? Not including caching? It's a complicated topic. You have to measure performance for your specific case. I'm just saying that implementing table partitioning in the application logic is a bad idea. Usually when someone comes up with it, it's because they're not quite across how indexes work

Comment: Ok thank you Nick, I read more about partitioning and it looks interesting since it is basically what was my id with the 6 tables example. But does it multiply the size of the database by 2? What is the impact on the DB size?

Comment: If you have two tables of a million rows each, or one table with two million rows that is partitioned, they are both the same size

Comment: Partitioning means you don't have to create separate tables. You create one table and partition it by something and when you query on it and put something in the `where` clause that matches the partition, it automatically  knows which piece of the table to look in and doesn't look in the other parts. Which is very similar to straighforward indexing

Comment: If you are concerned you may have a performance issue in a database, first learn about indexes and partitioning. Don't try and solve it with things in the application

Comment: Ok you can add these very interesting comments to your answer and I will select it. Perhaps also explain how index and partition differs and if they have synergies altogether! Thank you ~

Comment: I added some more detail

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to keep all "like" data in a single table, not split among multiples.  There are good reasons for this:

- Adding new combinations is easier.
- Maintaining the tables is easier.
- You an easily do queries "across" entities.
- Overall, the database is more efficient, because it is more likely that pages will be filled.

And there are other reasons as well.  In your case, you *might* have an argument for breaking the data into 6 separate tables.  The gain here comes from not having the `color` and `is_left_one` in the data.  That means that this data is not repeated 6 million times.  And that could save many tens of megabytes of data storage.

I say the last a bit tongue-in-cheek (meaning I'm not that serious).  Computers nowadays have so much member that 100 Mbytes is just not significant in general.  However, if you have a severely memory limited environment (I'm thinking "watch" here, not even "smart phone") then it might be useful.

Otherwise, partitioning is a fine solution that pretty much meets your needs.

Comment: Yes I also save the columns 'color' and boolean in the data. Thank you for the very good point. +1!

Answer (score 0):

For this:

```
WHERE color=blue AND is_left_one=true
```

The optimal index is

```
INDEX(color, is_left_one)  -- in either order
```

Having `id` first makes it useless for that `WHERE`.

It is generally bad to have multiple identical tables instead of one.

Comment: May you detail the "generally bad to have multiple identical tables instead of one"? I know that it is a (far) less pretty design but I need to squeeze out every bit of performance so my question is especially on the performance/memory/latency aspect

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL - For performance, let's see the SQL statements that cause the most drag on the server.  (I suspect that it is not just this `WHERE` clause.)